# printing prints slowly for bold text

Tags: php, javascript, printers, printer-properties

i have page , in this page i have around 45 lines ,

the first 5 lines are document heading, and this document heading css style is just font-family-arial, font-weight bold ,

and heading inserted inside the td , no more style,

problem is , this first 5 line print very dead slow, after 5the printer print the text very fastly, obviously the reset of the

text are just fonr-weight:normel, Pleawse advise some tip/ideas to increase the printing fast ,

(Am using dot matrix printer ,)

Comment: Also i increased the spooling, becoz we run system in network, so guess due to network trafic printing is slow, so i creased the spooling level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known issue with DMP (Dot Matrix Printer) as the printing from a web page goes as a image print. For bold-face printing it normally prints twice or very slowly (depending on the number of pins in the printer).

For one such issue, I rolled out a component to convert RTF to plain text with printer escape characters (for bold facing, double sizing, compressing fonts) and sent it as a text file to the printer.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a design issue with your printer: as you're saying, it's dot-matrix. These types of printers have very low DPI, so they're working around it by printing bolded text as normal text, but several times in the same area, slightly offset each time (whereas normal text is only printed once). That means that a line in bold text will take a multiple of the time necessary to print a normal line.

If this is a major issue, consider getting a laser printer - those print in near-constant time, regardless of page coverage.

Comment: +1 for still remembering what a dot matrix printer is :D  And also for giving a sensible answer about one!